# How do I find the View ID for the spinner itself?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I would like to implement an onclicklistener for a spinner once it is first clicked.

findViewById(R.id.spinner01) will return an AdapterView, with which you cannot implement an onClickListener.

Is there a way I can determine the View ID (as in, the non-AdapterView ID) of the actual button style grey instance that is displayed in a layout before the AdapterView is displayed?

Comment: Can you paste your XML for spinner here..

Comment: I didn't quite understand your problem... If you want to use a button, why don't you use findViewById(ButtonId)?

Comment: I don't think you need to implement onClickListener for this... You have to implement onItemClickListener

Comment: onItemClickListener will run when an item is selected from the AdapterView. I want to know when the spinner is first clicked...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
 @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(RESOURCE_ID);

        Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
        spin.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.spinner_id)//arg0.getId() will return you id of spinner         {
              //your code
            }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Spinner yields this error for me when i call setOnClickListener: "RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView"

Comment: try setOnTouchlistener instead of setOnclickListener

Answer (score 0):

The view you get with findViewById actually returns you a Spinner object if you refer to the android:id of a Spinner in XML. For when it is first clicked just give the spinner an onClickListener as shown by vipin or with an anonymous listener.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_SPINNER_ID);
spinner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() );
```

and implement the onClick function in the onClickListener (should be automatically generated for you by Eclipse.

Comment: Spinner yields this error for me when i call setOnClickListener: "RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView"

Comment: Well generally you would use an onItemSelectedListener for the spinner selection. Try an OnTouchListener and see if you get errors. It should work to assign multiple listeners assuming there is one for the default action of opening up a Dialog for selection.

Comment: Assigning an OnYouchListener yields the same error as OnClickListener for an AdapterView I'm afraid...